# Special navigation possible with css?

Tags: css, image, background, navigation

I have a navigation like this:

[image]

Could I do this with css? Or do I have to cut the background image and use it in my css? I was just wondering if it could be done with pure css and don't use the background-image.

I'm not the best in css so if this is possible could you maybe give some link or some keywords that I can search on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS , you can eventually use box-shadow and border-radius: **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxFGo)**
CSS

```
body , html{
background:#ACD1DF;
  margin:0;
}
nav {
  position:relative;
  height:80px;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px;
  background:#84C390;
  margin:0;
  padding:5px:
}
img {
  border-radius:100%;
  box-shadow:0 8px 5px -4px gray;/* shadow's size is reduce to only at bottom */
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
ul, li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 1em;
}
```

HTML use for demo:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">lien</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">lien</a></li>
  </ul>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/95x95/84C390&text=lorem"/>
</nav>
```